# Laravel upgrade 5.5 Error "Method getPath does not exist."

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-upgrade

I have upgraded Laravel from 5.2 to 5.5. All seems ok except one error `Method getPath does not exist.`. I can't see any trace hence unable to figure out why and where it is throwing this error. This is not coming everytime but sometimes.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're providing way too less information. Paste the entire stacktrace, or a screenshot of the full error page.

Comment: Please provide full error

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As I mentioned there is no stack trace of this error, that is the reason I am unable to figure out. I never got this error in `development`. I am getting this only on `Production`. Errors are logged in loggly and for this error unfortunately, there is no stack trace.

Comment: Sounds like it has something to do with routing

Comment: Make sure you update all dependencies too along with any other third party packages if you are using any.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getRoute();
```

To

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->uri();
```

Comment: Add some explanation to avoid this post to consider as low quality post by `stackoverflow`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure getRoute was deprecated but didn't want to make any assumptions and don't know for sure which version. The fix works in Laravel 5.8